# How to Resolve a System.NotImplementedException in C# Switch Statement?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# console application whose purpose is to read a CSV, assign a weight for a given entry so that the weights can categorize the lattitude/longitude coordinate in a larger mapping application.  The portion of the application that reads the CSV grouping file is as follows:

```
var otherWeights = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
var distressedWeights = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
var industrialWeights = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
var officeWeights = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
var retailWeights = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();

//TODO: Get Listof SIC Codes and manually assign (a) a category (distressed, industrial, office or retail) and (b) a weight
otherWeights.Add("Other", 5);
distressedWeights.Add("Distressed", 4);
industrialWeights.Add("Industrial", 3);
officeWeights.Add("Office", 2);
retailWeights.Add("Retail", 1);
//These are used in assignments below
//TODO: get a unique list of all SIC present in this dataset.. probably about 1,000, and save as spread sheet

//establish connection to specified CSV.
string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dataDirectory + ";"
+ "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";

using (var txt = new StreamReader(dataDirectory + "SICGroupingSummary.csv"))
using (var reader = new CsvReader(txt, true))
{
    var header = reader.GetFieldHeaders();
    var sicIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, "SIC_Code");
    var sicDesc = Array.IndexOf(header, "SIC_Description");
    var categoryIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, "Category");
    var weightIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, "Weight");

    foreach (string[] row in reader)
    {
        switch (row[sicIndex])
        {
            case "Distressed":
                distressedWeights[row[sicIndex]] = Int32.Parse(row[weightIndex]);
                break;
            case "Industrial":
                industrialWeights[row[sicIndex]] = Int32.Parse(row[weightIndex]);
                break;
            case "Office":
                officeWeights[row[sicIndex]] = Int32.Parse(row[weightIndex]);
                break;
            case "Retail":
                retailWeights[row[sicIndex]] = Int32.Parse(row[weightIndex]);
                break;
            case "Other":
                otherWeights[row[sicIndex]] = Int32.Parse(row[weightIndex]);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Category not found");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the application, I receive an error stating:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred
```

pointing to the last portion of the switch statement.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
at BuildALU.Run() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MapLarge\dataparse\DataParse  
\ActualLandUseMap\BuildALU.cs:line 79
at DataParse.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MapLarge
\dataparse\DataParse\Program.cs:line 14
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, 
String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,   
ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I've ensured that all 5 values are in the dictionary.  Can someone educate me on why this error is being thrown?  Is there a suggested approach to ensuring that the exception is handled?  If so, what do you recommend?

Comment: Go through in the debugger.  See what `row[sicIndex]` is when you hit the switch.  Clearly isn't none of the values shown.  Work your way back to see why it's an unexpected value.  Is the index improper given the circumstances, does the row not have a value it should have, does your file have an invalid value on one line, etc.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the throw new line and see what row[sicIndex] is equal to

Comment: In what way do you want to "resolve the error"?  If you don't want to throw an exception when encountering an unexpected value, remove the line that throws the exception (ideally replace it with something else, such as a logging statement).  If you want to keep the exception and fix the unexpected value, find where that value is coming from and change it.

Comment: Check the value of `row[sicIndex]` at the time when the exception is thrown. Your code is going to the `default` case because whatever that value is does not match any of the values that you've defined: "Distressed", "Industrial", "Office", "Retail", "Other".

Comment: Does row[sicIndex] need a cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change  `throw new NotImplementedException("Category not found");`
to

```
throw new NotImplementedException(String.Concat"Category not found :",row[sicIndex]));
```

Then hit yourself a few times when you realise you wanted something like

```
switch(row[sicIndex].Category)
```

Don't worry we've all done it.